# how to add announcement list to a master page in SP 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint, master-pages

I want to add an announcement list to my masterpage, so that these announcements are shown in all the pages in the sitecollection.

from googling i found out that we cannot add dynamic webparts to master page.

can this be achieved programmatically or through powershell.

also i want to show the latest 3 announcements ( modified by date)

is it possible???

thanks in advance

Praky

Answer (score 1):

Quite Simple really using the Content QUery WP. IN Presentation part of the Edit WP. Use the sort by Created in descending order and limit items to 3.